# I cannot display array data from session?

Tags: php

Please check the following code below i am trying to achieve a Session based Cart system for my site:

This is what happens when i post the form:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['addtocart'])):
$item = array(
  'package' => $_POST['item_name'],
  'amount' => $_POST['amount']
);
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $item;
endif;
```

Then the data is like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>;
  array(2) {
    ["package"]=>;
    string(42) "Bronze (Division V) ->; Bronze (Division V)"
    ["amount"]=>;
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=>;
  array(2) {
    ["package"]=>;
    string(46) "Bronze (Division V) ->; Challenger (Challenger)"
    ["amount"]=>;
    string(4) "1666"
  }
}
```

and i am trying to display data like this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item):
    echo $item->package;
endforeach;
```

The result is nothing so what did i do wrong here?

Comment: Did you start `session` when you added product to your cart?

Comment: at this point you should have your debugging on. Try to provide more details. is this a one page script?

Comment: you need use @session_start(); before you can print_r($_SESSION['cart'],1);

Comment: Add [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) at the beginning of your script.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the `package` as an array item and trying to retrieve it as an object property.

So try changing this line

```
echo $item->package;
```

To

```
 echo $item['package'];
```

Your **current** code should be throwing an error, Something along the lines of

```
Warning: PHP Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$package
```

Comment: This might be it, I have debugging off since its WordPress at the moment. But the above does make sense. Is the code I have the best solution or do you recommend a different method?

Comment: If you only want to use the `$_SESSION` to store the input variables then your method looks ok, IMHO.
Also its highly likely that the "debugging mode off"  is suppressing the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

As @davejal mentioned you should turn some debugging options on to get more error details while developing. How to do so can be read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/845025/3948598

> You need to enable error display in the php.ini.
>
> Check this page in the PHP documentation for information on the 2
>   directives: `error_reporting` and `display_errors`. `display_errors` is
>   probably the one you want to change.

Comment: sorry for that, wen't to fast on this one. still you should consider turning the display of errors on as i mentioned in my edit